# "where" on json field causing Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server-2016, json

I have a table:

when I select all from the table:

```
 SELECT JSON_VALUE(LastReadings, '$.lastReadings."7-temp".value') as x FROM
(VALUES    
(2,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":12}},"customId":null}'),
(3,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":32}},"customId":null}'),
(4,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":22}},"customId": null}'),
(5,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value": 12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":123}},"customId": null}')    
)
[AmirTestTable](Id,LastReadings )
```

I get

```
+-----+
|  x  |
+-----+
|  12 |
|  32 |
|  22 |
| 123 |
+-----+
```

However when i try to add a where clause:

```
 SELECT JSON_VALUE(LastReadings, '$.lastReadings."7-temp".value') as x 
 FROM
(VALUES
  (2,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":12}},"customId":null}'),
  (3,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":32}},"customId":null}'),
  (4,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value":12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":22}},"customId": null}'),
  (5,N'{"groups": [],"lastReadings": {"amir": {"name": "Ink","value": 12.0},"7-temp": {"name": "Temperature","value":123}},"customId": null}')
)
[AmirTestTable](Id,LastReadings )
where JSON_VALUE(LastReadings, '$.lastReadings."7-temp".value') > 12.0
```

I get the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

If I change the 123 value to 99 the query works, or if i change the where clause to > 12. It also works if i cast it explicitly to a number.

I don't understand why it doesn't work directly though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with JSON specifically. You see the same with

```
SELECT 1
WHERE  '123' > 12.0;
```

[`JSON_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn921898.aspx) has a return type of `nvarchar(4000)`.

The literal `12.0` has a datatype of `numeric(3,1)`.

As `numeric`/`decimal` has a [higher datatype precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `nvarchar` the result of the function call is cast to `numeric(3,1)`

[image]

You can use an explicit cast to control the scale and precision used yourself.

e.g.

```
 CAST(JSON_VALUE(LastReadings, '$.lastReadings."7-temp".value') AS NUMERIC(4,1)) > 12.0
```

Would work fine for your example data.

Comment: So really the problem is that whatever i compare it to sets the implicit cast?

Comment: @Amir - yes. As long as whatever you are comparing it to has a higher precedence than `nvarchar`. If you use `12` then that is `int` so you don't get the issue either.

Comment: Sorry for the messy question, when you edited it did you use tags I dont know or did you do it manually? I used <code></code>

Comment: Don't use those tags. Just indent the content you want formatted as code. You can select the desired text and then use the `{}` button in the editor toollbar,